# Javascript prototype question on the `new` keyword

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
    console.log(this)
}

const test = new Person(); //A
const test1 = Person(); //B
```

Question:

if i run both function, the first function (A) will return:

```
Person {firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined, age: undefined, eyeColor: undefined}
```

but when i run the function (B) it return `window` object

is the new keywords doing this?

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this = Object.assign(Person);
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
    return this;
}
```

hence i don't see the window object? can someone explain and help on this please.

thanks

Comment: Uuh, you're mixing up the programming language (Javascript) with the environment (browser). You can run JS in non-browser environments too. The scenario A is expected, you're not passing any ctor arguments, so everything is nil. Statement B is just making a function reference to the ctor, it's not actually invoking it.

Comment: Yes, `new` creates an instance of an object and that object is what `this` points to inside the function. If you don't use `new` you're just running a function and all the normal rules for determining what `this` refers to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's roughly correct. The `new` keyword creates a new object, sets Person.prototype to be that object's prototype, and then invokes Person, with `this` set equal to the newly created object. If your function does not explicitly return anything, then the newly created object will be implicitly returned (and that's typically the behavior you want for a constructor, so i recommend omitting a return statement).

You can read more about the new operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function  `this` refer to caller. In your code caller is `windows` object. In the other hand, when you use  `new` keyword, this create a new object and
 set it's prototype equal to master, means `object`.